# javascript autoclick with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, click

I want to make a form where if someone type the word `ok` in the input field, the button will be auto clicked. How can this be done?

```html
<input type="text" id="text"><br><br>

<input id="autoclick" type="button" value="type ok">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text"><br><br>
<input type="button" id="button" value="type ok">
```

jQuery:

```
$('#text').on('keyup', function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'ok'){
        $('#button').trigger('click');
    }
})
// this block is for test
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/fnoL4j7m/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  <input type="text" id="text"><br><br>

<a href="#" id="autoclick">
  <input type="button" id="button" value="type ok">
</a>
```

Jquery:

```
 $('#text').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='ok')
    {
    $( '#button' ).trigger( "click" );
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply **keyup** event on the input box.

> Every time something is entered, it will check if the input is "ok".
>
> If so, a click event is **triggered** on the button.

```
$("#text").on('keyup', function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'ok') {
    $('input[type="button"]').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Refer to this: https://jsfiddle.net/dts2aa5o/10/

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```js
$('#text').on('keyup', function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'ok'){
        $('#button').click()
    }
})
```